# Overflow-y affecting visibility of element within a container

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some content that has a negative position relative. I want the span's to appear above its container in the x-axis, but overflow-y is clipping my text. I need it to have a vertical scroller.

I don't want an horizontal scroll.
I want a vertical scroll.
The text should appear above the container.

How Can I do that?

```
<div id="test">
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span>   
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span>  
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span>   
</div>​


#test {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.row {
    position:relative;
    left:-11px;
    display: block;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jZrER/   . Try removing overflow-y to see what happens.
I need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e7MXD/  but with vertical scroll.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
The blue part is vertical scroller (I have no time to draw it).

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the negative position?, this seems like a design problem.

Comment: It is not text, They are images. I simplified the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone proves me wrong on this. I don't think it's possibly using overflow in css. I used overflow-x:visible;, and it seems the scroll bar has a built in crop function (after all, you wouldn't want content going over/under the scrollbar). There might be a clever way to replicate it however.

**Edit**: My 'proof' of this is if you put

```
overflow-x: visible; !important
overflow-y: auto;
```

it won't add scrolls, but if you remove `!important` it does.

Comment: Hummm are you saying that it is not possible to do this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it with css. I've tried it a bit of ways with no success. Could you "fake" it with a background image then a transparent scrolling div on top?

Comment: Not using overflow the way you would think. Maybe doing what Chris said, or something similar. If you could include what you are trying to accomplish through this, you might get suggestions for a good work around, or maybe something better to do.

Answer (score 0):

Than use `overflow-x: auto;` as well, or better yet, omit both and use `overflow: auto`.

Comment: No. I added more comments. I dont want an horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Still a little confused on what you're trying to achieve. I played around with this though.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7MXD/1/

```
<div id="test">
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span>   
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
    <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
     <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
     <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
     <span class="row"> Text Text Text </span> 
</div>​​​​

#test {

    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.span-container {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;    
overflow-y:scroll; 
overflow-x:visible;  
height:100px;   
    width:200px
}

.row {
    position:relative;
    left:-11px;
    display: block;
}​
```

Comment: I'm confused about what @Tony is trying to acheive as well. Perhaps the question could be reworded to be clearer.

Comment: I am trying to make it clear, :) ...
I just added a picture.... The blue thing in the picture is a vertical scroller.

Comment: There is more text in the div, but you will have to scroll vertically in order to see it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the -left position for the spans? or were you trying to accommodate for the scroll bar? The scroll bar will adjust itself accordingly if you take off that negative position.

Comment: The reason is that it will have to look like if it were partially outside its container. I do not want horizontal scrollbar, just vertical